# struts2 parameter mapping

Tags: struts2

Form is submitted through an Ajax request and all the parameters in the form are prefixed with a random number. Ex:

123456567_name, 123456567_age (Number 123456567 is dynamic)

I want to map those parameters to the action fields which are name and age.

Is there a way to tell struts2 to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal parameter injection functionality is provided by the [ParametersInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/interceptor/ParametersInterceptor.html) interceptor. I'm not aware of any way you could configure this interceptor to implement the behaviour you need, but you always have the option of extending the interceptor.

So you could [create your own interceptor](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-creating-own-interceptor/) by extending the ParametersInterceptor class. Here is a example of how you could do it:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack;

/**
 *  WARNING: Untested code !
 */
public class CustomParameterInterceptor extends ParametersInterceptor{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3673037400195648706L;

    @Override
    protected void setParameters(Object action, ValueStack stack, final Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        super.setParameters(action, stack, getRealParamMap(parameters));
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> getRealParamMap(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e  : parameters.entrySet()) {
            result.put(e.getKey().split("_")[1], e.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

If you intend to use this, you should probably replace my getRealParamMap method by something stronger.

Comment: Hi Alban, thanks for the suggestions and the code. This is a good solution but I want to find if there is any other way to do the same. I want to know whether their are any annotations which I can use on the Model class fields to match the request params with the field names.